# How to include two files (in different projects) with the same name?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, include, projects-and-solutions

Using Visual Studio C++ 2010.  I recently renamed some files and now I have two files with the same name in different projects (same solution).  Previously I had code like in my main project:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass x = new MyClass();
```

And this worked.  MyClass.h was in MyLibrary which was a separate project and I added the MyLibrary folder as an `"Additional Include Directories": $(SolutionDir)MyLibrary;`

Now, because of the renaming, I have two files named "MyClass.h", the original one in MyLibrary and the new one in my main project.  Now I get an error on compiling:

> 7>c:\myproject\mainthing.cpp(81): error C2065: 'MyClass' : undeclared
>   identifier

I'm guessing my original MyClass.h file is getting obscured by the new MyClass.h file in my main project.

I tried to do something like:

```
#include "MyLibrary/MyClass.h"
```

but this gets the red underline and doesn't compile.

How can I get the include to refer to the MyClass.h in MyLibrary project?

Answer (score 0):

Messing around with the includes it seems if I add the parent directory to the include path then it works:

That is, change:

```
#include "MyLibrary/MyClass.h"
```

to:

```
#include "../MyLibrary/MyClass.h"
```